# canvas width 100%

Tags: html5, canvas

как задать тегу canvas ширину 100%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно добавить твой код для рисования канвы в drawStuff() функцию

```js
(function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            /**
             * Your drawings need to be inside this function otherwise they will be reset when 
             * you resize the browser window and the canvas goes will be cleared.
             */
            drawStuff(); 
    }
    resizeCanvas();

    function drawStuff() {
            // do your drawing stuff here
    }
})();
```

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; } /* to remove the top and left whitespace */

html, body { width:100%; height:100%; } /* just to be sure these are full screen*/

canvas { display:block; } /* To remove the scrollbars */
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```